# Do not want to repeat an item in Series for n number of times

Tags: python, loops

I have a Series like this:

```
[['Buy',
 'Buy',
 'None',
 'Buy',
 'Buy',
 'Buy',
 'None',
 'None',
 'None',
 'None',
 'None',
 'None',
 'None',
 'None',
 'Buy',
 'None',
 'None',
 'None',
 'None',...]
```

of 419 such items.

For every day, one action is to be performed - and they are written in chronological order in this list. The action at index 1 in this list is to be performed on Day 1, index 2 to be performed on Day 2...etc

I have to ensure that if Action on Day 1 is '`Buy`' then there is no '`Buy`' for next 8 days. During these days any '`Buy`' needs to be replaced with '`None`'. I am trying a loop but struggling with the same.

Just to add, the above is a Series of Actions to be taken on different days. So in this example on Day1, action is to buy. On Day 2 again the action is to buy. On Day 3, action is to do None. So what I want is that if on Day 1 Action is buy, there is no buy for next 8 days.

Comment: If you have tried something already it would be good to include the code (preferably a minimum reproducible example). Without knowing what you tried it's hard to tell why it failed.

Comment: What do you mean by "Day 1"? Some examples would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys

actions = ['Buy',
 'Buy',
 'None',
 'Buy',
 'Buy',
 'Buy',
 'None',
 'None',
 'None',
 'None',
 'None',
 'None',
 'None',
 'None',
 'Buy',
 'None',
 'None',
 'None',
 'None']

index = 0

while index < len(actions):
   if actions[index] == "Buy":
      check_next = 1
      while check_next < 8:
         if index + check_next < len(actions):
            if actions[index + check_next] == "Buy":
               actions[index + check_next] = "None"
               check_next += 1
            else:
               print(actions)
               sys.exit()
         else:
            check_next += 1
         index += 1

   else:
      index += 1

print(actions)
```

Comment: What if this is a dataframe column and not a normal series